# SQLAlchmemy — get related objects with reflected tables

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am quite new to sqlalchemy, I guess I am missing just a little piece here.

There is this Database (sql):

```
create table CEO (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  name char(255) not null,
  primary key(id),
  unique(name)
);

create table Company (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  name char (255) not null,
  ceo int not null,
  primary key(id),
  foreign key(ceo) references CEO(id)
);
```

That code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship, Session

engine = create_engine(
  "mysql+pymysql:xxxxxxxx", 
  echo=True, 
  future=True
)

mapper_registry = registry()
Base = mapper_registry.generate_base()

#####################
## MAPPING CLASSES ##
#####################

class CEO(Base):
  __table__ = Table('CEO', mapper_registry.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
  companies = relationship('Company', lazy="joined")

class Company(Base):
  __table__ = Table('Company', mapper_registry.metadata, autoload_with=engine)

##########################
## FINALLY THE QUESTION ##
##########################

with Session(engine, future=True) as session:
  for row in session.query(CEO).all():
    for company in row.companies:
      ## Just the id of the Ceo is yielded here
      print(company.ceo)
```

So `CEO.companies` works as expected, but `Company.ceo` does not, even though the `FOREIGN KEY` is defined.

What is a proper setup for the `Company` Mapper class, such that `Company.ceo` yields the related object?

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out, that the automatic setup did not work, because the column `Company.ceo` exists in the Database and represents the ID of a given row. To make everything work, I needed to rename `Company.ceo` to `Company.ceo_id` and add the relation manually like so:

```
CompanyTable = Table('Company', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine) 

class Company(Base):
  __table__ = CompanyTable
  ceo_id = CompanyTable.c.ceo
  ceo = relationship('CEO')
```

I would like to know if it would be possible to rename the column within the `Table(…)` call, such that I could get rid of the extra `CompanyTable` thing.